# what could stop windows7 from pinging a certain device?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ping

We have a strange problem:

- Device 109: Laptop Win7
- Device 108: Epson WF2010 Printer
- Device 100: PC-Tower Win7
- Device 001: Router

Network is wireless 192.168.2.0
Subnet is 255.255.255.0

- 100 can ping all devices
- 001 lists all devices
- 109 can't ping 108 but all other devices including itself even if firewall is completely disabled.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to ping my IP address or name?  What result does Ping provide when you try to ping 108 from 109? If you `tracert` from 109 to 108 how far does it make it?  Also, can you clarify what you mean by "but all other devices including itself even if firewall is completely disabled." as that sentence currently doesn't make much sense... are you saying that .109 _can_ ping all other devices?

Comment: What happens when you adding this as network printer in the control panel > add printers options. Does '108' printer discovered and showing the list?.

Comment: @techie007: "Are you trying to ping my IP address or name?" Well, i don't know your IP-address but i ping the devices by their ip-adress.
I dont know what you do not understand. It simply means that 109 cant ping 108 but it can ping all other devices and even if its firewall is completely disabled, it still cant ping 108.